# Android HttpUrlConnection not working

Tags: java, android, httpclient, httpurlconnection

Basically, I'm trying to connect to a web interface through an Android App.

I managed to send commands to the form successfully using HttpClient. However, I want to accomplish this using HttpUrlConnection as recommended here http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html with the intention of having a faster and more energy efficient connection.

```
URL url = new URL("http://" + mIpAddress + ":" + mPort + "/command.html");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(URLEncoder.encode("parameter=" + value, "UTF-8");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

connection.connect();
```

Edit: No exceptions are being thrown since the code is executing just fine, the request is just probably not in the expected format by the server?

Comment: Hi I am using URLconnection above 28 but it showing error importing these libraries can you have any answer yes it is working now but showing error import why

Answer (score 5):

connnection.getInputStream() was required for the POST to work. Fixed.

Comment: It gives me an exception, FileNotFoundException

Comment: Wow. I was stuck in same problem since two hours. And this helped

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use to send http requests using HttpURLConnection, notice that the connection.connect() is right after setting up the HttpURLConnection not at the  end, also the setDoInput makes the request POST instead of the default get,

```
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    //conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
    // conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
    //conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    //conn.setDoInput(true);   //* uses POST
    // Starts the query
    conn.connect();
    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
    //String data = convertStreamToString(stream);
    int sz = stream.available();
    byte[] b = new byte[sz];
    stream.read(b);
    stream.close();
    String data = new String(b);
```

Comment: I just tried connecting before, as per your example, however the server is still not getting my command at all or not getting it properly.

Comment: would you post what is in your commad.html.  The code that I provided is used in a working application and it works fine when provided a valid url.

Answer (score 1):

Just add one line

```
connection.getRequestMethod();
```

and it will work.

I dont know why but this works for me after I have spent a whole day on it!

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information, like Exceptions, or the servers response? Does the server receives a your request?

However, I recommend you to use [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) which has been build on top of `HttpUrlConnection`

Comment: I'm not getting any exceptions, and no response either as far as I can tell. The server/site does not HAVE to send back a response right? 

I'm trying to avoid using third party libraries for now, since I only need a simple method to connect. But if all else fails, I will consider using okhttp, thanks for telling me about it!

Anyway, is there anything I can do to provide better information? Don't really know what to debug since connecting to the server seems to be a bit of a trial and error process.

Comment: are you running your http code in an own thread or async task? Since android 4.0 android won't let you execute blocking the main ui thread for long running things like http calls. Usually in this case an exception will be thrown, but maybe this is not  done on your test device for some reason ...

Comment: I'm running it properly in an AsyncTask. Basically, I have two methods in this class. One works using HttpClient (Apache I think) and the other one is using HttpUrlConnection. HttpClient is working fine, so there aren't issues with the thread, however HttpUrlConnection is giving me issues. This is my first time using networking in Java, so I'm probably missing something very simple for the above implementation... I also tried to compare the character encoding etc between the HttpClient and HttpUrlConnection, but I didn't see any differences.

Answer (score 0):

To share Data using HttpUrlConnection class 
Here is Simple Connection class this Will Help you to Connect With WS , and to pass data using JSON parsing ..

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class CommonConnectionClass {
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    public JSONObject getConnection(String u,JSONObject object){
        try {

            //URL url=new URL("https://e-gurukulam.000webhostapp.com/public_html/project/login.php"+u+".php");
            URL url=new URL("http://"+new Connection_Url_Setter().urlIp+"/classroom/"+u+".php");
           // URL url=new URL("http://192.168.43.120/classroom/"+u+".php");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json; charset=utf-8");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            if(object!=null) {
                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
                dataOutputStream.write(object.toString().getBytes());

            }
            int code=httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            if(code== HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                String inputLine;
                StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();


                BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                while((inputLine=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
                }
                jsonObject=new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

To use this class i use the Asyn class Like,...

```
class userNameFetchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {
            JSONObject object, jsonObject, json;
            JSONArray jsonArray;
            ArrayList<CreateGroupModel> lidList = new ArrayList<>();
            String lid, name;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("lid", sp.getString("lid", null));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                object = new JSONObject();
                CommonConnectionClass commonConnectionClass = new CommonConnectionClass();
                object = commonConnectionClass.getConnection("selectUserForGroup", jsonObject);
                return object;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
                jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                try {
                    jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        CreateGroupModel model = new CreateGroupModel();

                        json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        model.setLid(json.getString("relative_lid"));
                        model.setName(json.getString("name"));
                        model.setEmail(json.getString("email"));
                        model.setImage(json.getString("image"));

                        lidList.add(model);
                    }
                    viewstudentsadapterForCreateGroup viewstudentsadapterForCreateGroup = new viewstudentsadapterForCreateGroup(getApplicationContext(), lidList, createGroup_Activity.this);
                    listView.setAdapter(viewstudentsadapterForCreateGroup);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was actually NetworkOnMainThreadException thrown but not shown clearly in Logs